# PHP array_filter() removes empty elements from array but messes up their location

Tags: php, arrays

`Var_dump()` of my array *before* `array_filter()`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(2) "46" }
```

`Var_dump()` of my array *after* `array_filter()`:

```
array(1) { [1]=> string(2) "46" }
```

However I want to get `array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "46" }`, with the remaining element at the beginning of the array (0, not 1). How to do that?

Comment: `messes up their location`? No, actually it leaves the keys exactly as they were.... if you want to change that, then wrap your array_filter() call in an array_values() call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex an array.

```
$filtered_array = array_values(array_filter($array));
```